# windows batch script for renaming files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a lot of files in a windows folder. These file names contain a lot of underscores as well. E.g.:

> ```
> ad_iod_errr_opp12.txt  
> ghff_jjk56.txt  
> opr_sdr_ot_wrr_12ee.txt
> ```

I want to rename these files such that the last underscore and everything following it is removed and the files are renamed as follows:

> ```
> ad_iod_errr.txt
> ghff.txt
> opr_sdr_ot_wrr.txt
> ```

Note: The number of underscores varies. Some filenames may have just a single underscore, whereas other filenames may have up to 8 underscores. I am looking for a  Windows batch script which could do the trick and not PowerShell commands.

This is the code that I am using currently to rename the files considering that the file names have only one underscore in it:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL 
cd C:\Users\ambika.narayan.rao\JenkinsWorkspace 
SET "fname=*.txt" 
FOR %%i IN ("%fname%") DO FOR /f "delims=_" %%j IN ("%%i") DO ren "%%~i" "%%~j%%~xi" 
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
cd C:\Users\ambika.narayan.rao\JenkinsWorkspace
SET "fname=*.txt"
FOR %%i IN ("%fname%") DO FOR /f "delims=_" %%j IN ("%%i") DO ren "%%~i" "%%~j%%~xi"
GOTO :EOF   This is the code that I am using currently to rename the files considering that the file names have only one underscore in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 set "partsname=!filename:_= _!"
 FOR %%b IN (!partsname!) DO SET "newname=!filename:%%b=!%%~xa"
 ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!newname!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Perform a directory scan of all filenames matching the mask. WIth each name found, using delayed expansion, assign the name to `filename` and then replace each `_` with <kbd>Space</kbd>_

Use a simple `for` to assign `newname` to the original filename with the `_string` removed (replaced by *nothing*) and add back the extension using `%%~xa`. The last string assigned to `%%b` will be `_laststring.ext`, so the value assigned to `newname` will fit the processing requirement, so rename the file.

Comment: Although I like the basic idea, I'm afraid this fails if there is a file `test_A.txt_A.txt`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified script that I posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43403841), relying on a nice hack to remove the last portion of a string separated by a certain character – the underscore `_` in this case. Note that this fails in case any of the files contains exclamation marks `!` in their names. So this is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dp0."
set "_MASK=*_*.txt"

rem // Enumerate all matching files:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_SOURCE%\%_MASK%"') do (
    rem // Store current file name and extension:
    set "FILE=%%~nF" & set "FEXT=%%~xF"
    rem // Call sub-routine that removes the last `_`-separated part:
    call :GET_LAST_ITEM LAST RMND "%%~nF"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion to be able to read the variables:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Actually rename current file: */
    ECHO ren "!FILE!!FEXT!" "!RMND!!FEXT!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:GET_LAST_ITEM  rtn_last  rtn_without_last  val_string
    ::This function splits off the last `_`-separated item of a string.
    ::Note that exclamation marks must not occur within the given string.
    ::PARAMETERS:
    ::  rtn_last            variable to receive the last item
    ::  rtn_without_last    variable to receive the remaining string
    ::  val_string          original string
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "STR=_%~3"
    set "PRE=" & set "END=%STR:_=" & set "PRE=!PRE!_!END!" & set "END=%"
    endlocal & set "%~1=%END%" & set "%~2=%PRE:~2%"
    exit /B
```

To be able to also handle file names with exclamation marks correctly, here is a different approach:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dp0."
set "_MASK=*_*.txt"

rem // Enumerate all matching files:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_SOURCE%\%_MASK%"') do (
    rem // Store current file name and extension:
    set "FILE=%%~nF" & set "FEXT=%%~xF"
    rem // Initialise some variables:
    set "NAME=" & set "ITEM="
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose `!` in file names:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Loop through all partial file names separated by `_`; since every
    rem    `_` is replaced by `" "` and the whole string is enclosed in `""`,
    rem    we effectively get a list of quoted file name parts, which were
    rem    originally separated from each other by `_`: */
    for %%I in ("!FILE:_=" "!") do (
        rem /* Rebuild file name but delayed by one name part; the `for /F` loop
        rem    iterates once and transports the result beyond `endlocal`: */
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%E in ("!NAME!!ITEM!_") do (
            endlocal
            set "NAME=%%E"
        )
        rem // Belatedly store currently iterated file name part:
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem /* Actually rename current file; superfluous leading and trailing `_`
    rem    are removed from the rebuilt file name: */
    ECHO ren "!FILE!!FEXT!" "!NAME:~1,-1!!FEXT!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having successfully tested the scripts, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands** to actually rename any files!