# How to processing only specific delimiter when string have same characters with delimiter

Tags: batch-file

How to processing  only specific delimiter when string have same characters  with delimiter?.

Sample.bat

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Load  Variable From data*.txt

set /a Line=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (data*.txt) do (
    set /A Line+=1
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "data_in!Line!=%%b" & set "data_out!Line!=%%c"
    )
)

set data

pause
```

data1.txt :

```
a.pnh_111
bb.pop_222
c c.oiu_333
```

data2.txt :

```
_dd.pnh_444
e_e.pop_555
ff_.oiu_666
```

Output from data1.txt

```
data_in1=a.pnh
data_in2=bb.pop
data_in3=c c.oiu

data_out1=111
data_out2=222
data_out3=333
```

IT WORKED PERFECTLY at data1.txt

But the output from data2.txt NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED  because  it have 2 character "_"

Output from data2.txt what i want:

```
data_in1=_dd.pnh
data_in2=e_e.pop
data_in3=ff_.oiu

data_out1=444
data_out2=555
data_out3=666
```

when i replaced  separator "_" to "(separator)" at all data*.txt like:

data1.txt :

```
a_a.pnh(separator)111
abb.pop(separator)222
ccc.oiu(separator)333
```

and change delimiter to:

```
/f "tokens=1,2 delims=(separator)" %%b in ("%%a") do (
```

Of course  it not working.

Notes :
data*.txt written by another program. Currently by using character "_" as separator but i can change  it to another character ( i cannot predicted  what the output will be written into data.txt .maybe it have same character with separator i use)

Comment: Normally for csv file, people use `"` or `'` to have a text boundary. If you can't do that, make your delimiter more than one character if you can like `#$#`.

Comment: Use a set command to change the underscore to a space.  Then put that variable into a normal `FOR` command.  It will then assign the last part of the data to the variable.

Comment: If the trailing numbers destined for data_out# always have three places use substrings `:~-3` to extract .

Comment: One time you use Counter and then increment Line?

Comment: @LotPings ,The trailing numbers destined for data_out# not necessarily 3 characters ,and Sorry about counter it is not involved with the problem, I mistakenly put it in this question ,

Comment: But the trailing number is delimited by an underscore? Unprecise demo data doesn't help to find an algorythm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With changed files

data1.txt :

```
a.pnh_1
bb.pop_22
c c.oiu_333
```

data2.txt :

```
_dd.pnh_4444
e_e.pop_55555
ff_.oiu_666666
```

This batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\03\SO_50163726_2.cmd
@echo off & Setlocal 
:: Load  Variable From data*.txt
set Cnt=0
for %%A in (data*.txt) do for /f "delims=" %%B in (%%A) DO Call :ProcLine %%B
set data
pause
goto :Eof

:ProcLine
set /A Cnt+=1
set "Line=%~1"
Call :GetNum %Line:_= %
Rem Echo Num=%Num%
Call Set "Line=%%Line:_%Num%=%%"
set "data_in%Cnt%=%Line%" 
set "data_out%Cnt%=%Num%"
Goto :Eof

:GetNum
if "%~2" neq "" (shift&goto :GetNum)
Set Num=%1
Goto :Eof
```

will produce this output:

```
data_in1=a.pnh
data_in2=bb.pop
data_in3=c c.oiu
data_in4=_dd.pnh
data_in5=e_e.pop
data_in6=ff_.oiu
data_out1=1
data_out2=22
data_out3=333
data_out4=4444
data_out5=55555
data_out6=666666
```

Comment: See revised batch version

Comment: Your answer is very confusing to me, but I try to understand it

Comment: That's the best way to learn. Don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand a command.

Comment: Nice one, +1! But what happens when an input line is `a.pnh_111_111`, or it contains `!`-marks?

Comment: @aschipfl for the 1st that's OPs definition trailing number delimited by an underscore, for the second as I don't like enabling/disabling delayed expansion I just changed my answer to a version with call set and doubled percent signs

Comment: For the 1st part, what I meant, is: `a.pnh_111_111` should be split into `a.pnh_111` and `111`; your code returns `a.pnh_111` and `111`; of course we do not know whether or not such strings might occur...

Comment: @aschipfl Ahh ok, if the traling `_111` is a repeated pattern that will get lost on shortening the line.

Comment: Yes. This could be avoided by pre-appending some illegal character (if there are any) and including them for the sub-string replacement: `Call Set "Line=%%Line%%|"`, `Call Set "Line=%%Line:_%Num%|=%%"` (using `|` here)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a standard `for` loop to split each line string at every `_` symbol? When you enclose the string in between `""` and replace every `_` by `" "`, you get partial strings enclosed in between `""`; so for instance, `e_e.pop_555` becomes `"e" "e.pop" "555"`. Hence you can loop through them and reassemble them in a new variable and dismiss the last item, thus getting `e_e.pop` and `555`. This is faster than `goto` or `call`, because `for` loops are cached in memory.

Here is an example code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (input file; use first command line argument)

rem // Initialise counter:
set /A "COUNT=0"
rem // Read input file line by line, ignoring empty lines:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Store current line:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Increment counter:
    set /A "COUNT+=1"
    rem // Initialise interim variables:
    set "COLL=" & set "ITEM="
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Split line at every `_` and loop through items
    rem    (`?`, `*`, `<`, `>` and `"` must not occur): */
    for %%I in ("!LINE:_=" "!") do (
        rem /* Append previous item to variable; use `for /F`
        rem    to transport value beyond `endlocal` barrier: */
        for /F "delims=" %%K in ("COLL=!COLL!_!ITEM!") do (
            endlocal
            set "%%K"
        )
        rem // Store current item for next iteration, remove `""`:
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem /* Store appended string to `data_in` variable, then
    rem    store last item to `data_out` variable; use `for /F`
    rem    to transport value beyond `endlocal` barrier: */
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ("data_in!COUNT!=!COLL:~2!") do (
        for /F "delims=" %%J in ("data_out!COUNT!=!ITEM!") do (
            endlocal
            set "%%I" & set "%%J"
        )
    )
)
rem // Return stored data:
set data_

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach does not lose any exclamation marks (`!`) in the input strings or cause other trouble with them. However, the following characters are not allowed: `?`, `*`, `<`, `>` and `"`.

---

Given there are no exclamation marks (`!`) in the data files, the script can be simplified to this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (input file; use first command line argument)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise counter:
set /A "COUNT=0"
rem // Read input file line by line, ignoring empty lines:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!_FILE!") do (
    rem // Store current line:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Increment counter:
    set /A "COUNT+=1"
    rem // Initialise interim variables:
    set "COLL=" & set "ITEM="
    rem /* Split line at every `_` and loop through items
    rem    (`?`, `*`, `<`, `>` and `"` must not occur): */
    for %%I in ("!LINE:_=" "!") do (
        rem // Append previous item to variable:
        set "COLL=!COLL!_!ITEM!"
        rem // Store current item for next iteration, remove `""`:
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
    )
    rem /* Store appended string to `data_in` variable, then
    rem    store last item to `data_out` variable: */
    set "data_in!COUNT!=!COLL:~2!" & set "data_out!COUNT!=!ITEM!"
)
rem // Return stored data:
set data_
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

Here is a totally different approach based on a nice hack that I already used in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43403841):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (input file; use first command line argument)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise counter:
set /A "COUNT=0"
rem // Read input file line by line, ignoring empty lines:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!_FILE!") do (
    rem // Increment counter:
    set /A "COUNT+=1"
    rem /* Split current line at last `_`, then store the string before to
    rem    `data_in` variable and the string after to `data_out` variable: */
    call :GET_LAST_ITEM data_out!COUNT! data_in!COUNT! "%%L"
)
rem // Return stored data:
set data_
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B


:GET_LAST_ITEM  rtn_last  rtn_without_last  val_string
    ::This function splits off the last `_`-separated item of a string.
    ::Note that `!`, `^` and `"` must not occur within the given string.
    ::PARAMETERS:
    ::  rtn_last            variable to receive the last item
    ::  rtn_without_last    variable to receive the remaining string
    ::  val_string          original string
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "STR=_%~3"
    set "PRE=" & set "END=%STR:_=" & set "PRE=!PRE!_!END!" & set "END=%"
    endlocal & set "%~1=%END%" & set "%~2=%PRE:~2%"
    exit /B
```

The following characters are not allowed for this: `!`, `^` and `"`.

Comment: Another confusing method ,but i like it ,because have lot advantage

Comment: The most confusing part is toggling delayed expansion in order to handle `!` properly. If you can say there are no `!` in the strings, I could simplify the script...