# Create folders named from part of filename before last underscore and move corresponding files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I use the following batch file for creating folders and moving corresponding files based on part before the underscore. However some files now include two underscores and Therefore I would like the script to produce folder names from the part before the last underscore, not the first.

Like this:

> ```
> file1_e_cont.pdf --> file1_e\
> file2_conter.pdf --> file2\
> ```

Any suggestions for tweaking this script to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SRC=."
set "DST=."

for %%F in ("%SRC%\*_*.*") do if exist "%%F" (
    for /f "delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nF") do (
        if not exist "%DST%\%%D\" md "%DST%\%%D\"
        move "%SRC%\%%D_*.*" "%DST%\%%D\"
    )
)
endlocal & pause & exit /b
```

I'm aware there are several questions like mine around, however I haven't been able to implement these solutions on my case since this is all new to me.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173717)…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks. I get "Environment variable data_ not defined" when I run it. How do I define this variable? I would like to read and write to the same folder. Could you specify which part I should change in the script, for it to read my sourcefiles? (I'm looking into the non-! script )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a script based on the second approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173717):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0." & rem // (target directory; `.` means current, `%~dp0.` is parent of script)
set "_MASK=*.pdf"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "!_ROOT!" && (
    rem // Read input file line by line, ignoring empty lines:
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "!_MASK!"') do (
        rem // Store current base name:
        set "FILE=%%~nL"
        rem // Initialise interim variables:
        set "COLL=" & set "ITEM="
        rem /* Split base name at every `_` and loop through items
        rem    (`?`, `*`, `<`, `>` and `"` must not occur): */
        for %%I in ("!FILE:_=" "!") do (
            rem // Append previous item to variable:
            set "COLL=!COLL!_!ITEM!"
            rem // Store current item for next iteration, remove `""`:
            set "ITEM=%%~I"
        )
        rem // Create sub-directory named with appended string:
        if not exist "!COLL:~2!\*" mkdir "!COLL:~2!"
        rem // Move current file into sub-directory without overwriting:
        if not exist "!COLL:~2!\!FILE!%%~xL" (
            ECHO move "!FILE!%%~xL" "!COLL:~2!\!FILE!%%~xL"
        )
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

Note that there must not occur any exclamation marks (`!`) in the paths!

To actually move files, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command**!
To suppress `1 file(s) moved.` messages, **replace the upper-case `ECHO` command by `> nul`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great. I will try and understand all parts. One question: If I want the target directory where my folders are created to be a networkdrive using pushd/popd. Would it be like set "_ROOT= pushd \\Z:\Folder\subfolder"? Where would I place the popd? I also execute the .bat file in the files folder through cmd from another network folder using popd/pushd fin cmd.

Comment: No, you cannot do that within the `set` command line. Please see my edit, which incorporates the `pushd`/`popd` commands…

Comment: Ok. It seems it cant find the file to execute when I introduce the pushd/popd part. Is it Maybe because I pushd already to navigate to the source folder in cmd? From Where i then run the batch file

Comment: What do you mean by *»the file to execute«*?

Comment: I mean the batch file which i run. The script above. I do this in cmd: pushd path//to/folder/file.bat

Comment: Well, you cannot change into a file but only into a directory. *N. B.:* the Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`…

Comment: My separators are indeed correct in the script though and I'm changing to a folder first, then I run the file. I guess I'll play around with it and hopefully make it run also when specifying my own paths in the script. Thanks for your advice